# Rediscovering an idea - tell or hide?

Tags: united-states, authorship, plagiarism

I discovered an idea independently. I searched previously and found no prior work. Today, I discovered prior work completely by accident. The field's in STEM, and I'm in US.

Can I still take full credit if I just say I discovered it independently? Or should I lie and say I've never seen it? I have no moral qualms with latter since I'm not lying when I say I did it myself, and I really need the credit for it.

Comment: Hmm, what precisely do you expect people to reply to this question? Actually, I think you already know the answer yourself. Or to put it differently: If you really had no moral qualms about this, I believe you wouldn't be asking this.

Comment: Sooner or later people will know that it is not you.    If you can find it, surely another person will stumble on what you've found.  In my areas, there are many instances where an idea is 're-discovered'.  In most cases, the original source is credited.  In research, it is quite normal to find that your idea is not new.  I'm especially happy if my idea appeared  in a good/top venue, though I'm not the author.  At least my idea was good!

Comment: What "credit" do you expect to get?

Comment: @BryanKrause Recognition of skill. I don't care for profit, but I do need self-advertising points.

Comment: Recognition by who? Who are you self-advertising to? Why do you think anything but honesty would grant you more of this "credit"?

Comment: @BryanKrause Employers and field practitioners, but mainly former. Honesty risks being perceived as dishonesty as anyone can claim they reinvented something, yet it's harder to accuse of dishonesty on not knowing something's already invented. I have no problem acknowledging reinvention _after_ publishing my work.

Comment: It seems to me that if you claim to have discovered something as if you're the only one that's done it, you're just telling everyone you weren't very good at searching the literature.

Comment: What you discovered is probably known already to those in the field. If you say you discovered it for the first time you will be refuted, possibly rudely so. Be content with the insight you got from your rediscovery. That isn't nothing, but it isn't something you advertise (other than to your mom).

Comment: @Buffy Shunning who seek due credit and career opportunities is a good waving of academia red flag. I'm an individual with living needs, not a science martyr.

Comment: @user689325 the point is that *you probably should have found it*, and not having found it earlier doesn't look good on you.

Answer (score 0):

Some rediscoveries are interesting. Especially in mathematics, discovering a new way to prove something already known can still be interesting, since it's partly about the "journey" to get there, and the possibility that the same approach might help solve other problems.

In other areas, sometimes the isolation of different fields leads to things being rediscovered because people are using different language/conventions in their work. It can be very useful to recognize that actually the technique for doing one thing in field A is related to something else in field B. Connecting the two can create an entire new bridge between the fields.

If you try to publish something as new that isn't, or try to tell other people you discovered a new thing that isn't, it will be a bit embarrassing for you when someone catches the duplication and tells you it's not new and that it's actually just that your literature search was poor. It's far more efficient to hire someone who can find things that already exist than someone who spends time rediscovering what's already known.

I don't see much benefit to dishonesty here. You can say what you've done, emphasize any part of it that is new, yet acknowledge that the conclusion has been reached before. This sort of thing happens all the time in research.

Comment: Hmmm. A new and novel proof of a known theorem isn't "rediscovering" anything. It is a genuine advance if the method can be otherwise applied. In many cases in math, the proof is more important than the theorem statement.

Comment: If it's never a good idea, why does it happen, with rediscoverers benefitting before or even after the duplication is spotted? This case is special because if it was widely known, it'd almost certainly be widely applied, yet it isn't. Search incompetence is a price I'm willing to pay for strong technical competence.

Comment: @Buffy That's what I was trying to convey, I'd invite an edit if you think it wasn't clear.

Comment: @user689325 Most of those cases I can think of involved the initial discovery being poorly communicated either due to the discoverer not fully knowing what they had or from barriers in language and research dissemination before the internet. I'm not convinced that technical competence doesn't include search competence, I think one of the key skills a PhD student learns is how to find information they need and therefore both not waste their time and also understand what should be done next.

Comment: Maybe an example from biology or medicine would be better. ;-)

Comment: @Buffy Harder for me to think of useful rediscoveries in those areas - usually what we need in biology and medicine is **replication** which is entirely different. Mendelian genetics maybe but that's less a case of a particular rediscovery and more a case of appreciating an earlier finding due to other advances in theory.

Comment: If it were inclusive there wouldn't be dedicated professions for it. Many companies want someone who excels at product design, not dig in deep web which is something they hire others to do. Dodging the matter for sake of some idealized ethics won't stop those like me from proceeding with lies. It's more productive to help us lie, or to help sell our competence despite rediscovery - at least when we're honest.